# Version History shows field was updated, even though it wasn't

Tags: sharepoint-online, version-history

In my SharePoint document library, I have a date column with a default date (i.e. today's date).  This works fine.

My problem is: whenever I update the document itself, or any other metadata besides this date column, the version history shows this date column has changed for every version - even though its value was not changed.  It's cluttering the view and will make auditing difficult.

[image]

What am I likely doing wrong here?  Here is the field setup:

[image]

Comment: How is that date populated?  Can you post more info about the column? A screenshot of the column setup?

Comment: What value is stored in date field? Or it stores the today's date whenever the document/metadata is updated?

Comment: I've added an image to show the field setup - the date defaults to today, but should allow the user to change it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint online and I cannot reproduce your issue.

I created a date field named Next Approval Date, set it default value to "Today's Date".

When I update the document itself, or any other metadata besides this date column, the version history doesn't shows this date column.

[image]

For your issue, check whether there is workflow which update the field.

Create a new date field in the document library and compare whether the issue exists.

Create a new document library and add the date field to the new document library and compare whether the issue exists.